# fixed element is lost when it is on top of another absolute

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have an arrow for the navigation that is fixed, its operation is correct, until it passes over an absolute element with a sliding animation to the left, at that moment my "fixed" arrow goes along with the animation, it is lost from the screen.

I have two absolute divs in a relative container, when the user scrolls up to that position the two divs move out of the screen, left and right respectively. When the animation is triggered, my navigation arrow falls with it.

```
//this is my scss

/*******
 ARROW
********/

@import '../../scss/variables';

.arrow{
display: block;
position: fixed;
 right: 15px;
 bottom: 15px;
  svg{
    fill: #fff;
    width:50px;
  }
}
.my_bounce {
  animation-name: my_bounce;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

/***********
BOXES
************/
.about_cont{
  background: url('../../images/about-movil.jpg') top center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.about_boxes{
  display: flex;
  width: 50vw;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Panton';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;;
}
#about_box_1{
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: $sec;
  left: 0;
  p{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}
#about_box_2{
  color: #fff;
  background: $prim;
  right: 0;
 p{
   font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Can you also post your HTML that is using this style?

Answer (score 0):

Without Html file we can not tell about that code.Html file matter with css file

Answer (score 0):

Since we can't see your html we can't be certain what the problem is, but I'm pretty sure that adding

```css
z-index: 1;
```

to your arrow will fix the problem. If that doesn't work, try a bigger number.